# Geometric meaning of the dot product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I'm trying to understand exactly what the dot product represents outside the special case of two vectors being orthogonal. I know that if $\vec a$ is perpendicular to $\vec b$, then the dot product is the area of the parallelogram bounded by the vectors. But does the dot product represent when they are not orthogonal?

I know it has something to do with scalar projection. Since $\text{comp}_ab=\cfrac{a\cdot b}{\Vert a \Vert}$ then $$a \cdot b = \Vert a\Vert \cdot \text{comp}_ab$$
But what does that look like?

Comment: When  they are perpendicular, their dot product is just 0.

Comment: @Trebor I'm aware, since $\theta=\pi/2 \implies \Vert a \Vert \Vert b \Vert \cos\theta = 0$. But I'm interested in the geometric picture of $a\cdot b$

Comment: Therefore currently the statement in your question about the area stuff is incorrect.

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a ruler pointing in some direction and you have a distant light shining towards it and there is a wall behind the the ruler. The projection is the shadow cast. The angle between the ruler and the wall will change the length of the shadow. You can imagine this easily enough or just go experiment with it. Clearly if the ruler is normal/perpendicular to the wall then no shadow is cast and if it's parallel to the wall then the shadow length will be the same as the ruler.

$proj_{ruler}\; wall = shadow$ [in math we like to do things backwards so this is really $proj_{wall}\; ruler = shadow$]

$a \cdot b = \|a\|\cdot\|b\|\cdot cos(\theta)$

So the dot product is the projection of $a$ on to $b$ but the magnified by $b$. So it is a "scaled projection".

If you want, you can think of it as the area of the rectangle formed by sides of length $comp_b a$ and $b$ which is the same as the area of $comp_a b$ and $a$. Or if you like to think of vectors then it is taking the component of a on b, rotating that perp to $b$ and that will form a rectangle who's area is the dot project of $a$ and $b$.

Ultimately it is up to you to think about it how you want so you have an understanding.

E.g., take $a = <l, 0>$ and $b = <x,y>$ wlog.

The angle between them is $\theta = \cos^{-1}(x/r)$

So $a \cdot b = \|a\| \cdot \|b|\|\cdot \cos(\theta) = l r x/r = l x$

It doesn't even matter what $y$ is, how nice. if you change $y$ you are not changing the projection and it makes sense if you think of "light" going in the $<0,-1>$ direction and projecting on to $b$ on to $a$. Think of $b$ as the ruler and $a$ as the wall.

$a \cdot b = <l, 0> \cdot <x,y> = l x + 0 y$

What is $l x$? It's also the area of a rectangle with sides $l$ and $x$.

or if we have $c = <0,x>$ then it's $a \times c = \|a'\|\cdot \|c\|\cdot \sin(\alpha)$ but $\alpha = 90^o$.

It should be noted that the nice thing about the dot product is that it is a general object rather than what you initially learn. It's really just a type of multiplication defined on vector spaces. Remember that vector spaces too are also general objects. You can have vector spaces of functions, complex numbers, vector spaces of vector spaces, etc. The dot product can take different forms but what is important is that it lets us "multiply" vectors and it has certain properties. A vector space is essentially a group with "scalar multiplication" attached(and this is ultimately what allows us to represent vectors as components, because there is an interaction between the scalar field and the vector space). In more general contexts these specific ideas may not translate well unless you understand how to see them more abstractly. E.g., functions can have angles between them, lengths, etc and you can graph a function as a vector... but it's only because one makes analogy with say Euclidean vector spaces which ultimately come from Cartesian coordinates which are just real numbers.

All of mathematics is generalization from 0, it's quite simple, probably the simplest thing ever.

Comment: +1. My edit was for visual style. In LaTex \| looks better than ||. And I prefer to put \cdot between consecutive \|.

Answer (score 0):

Let a triangle $ABC$, with $\overrightarrow {AB}:=\overrightarrow a$ and $\overrightarrow {AC}:=\overrightarrow b$. Suppose additionally that the angle between two vectors is $θ_{({\overrightarrow a},{\overrightarrow b})}:= θ<\frac π2$. A *Eucledean* point of view will give us that the projection of $AC$ on $AB$ is $|proj_{AB}AC|=|AC|cosθ$. Now, analytic geometry defines the inner product between  $\overrightarrow a$ and $\overrightarrow b$ as $\overrightarrow a \cdot\overrightarrow b=\Vert \overrightarrow a\Vert \Vert \overrightarrow b\Vert cosθ$ (1). The vector of the projection of $\overrightarrow b$ on $\overrightarrow a$ is given by $proj_{\overrightarrow a}\overrightarrow b=\frac {\Vert \overrightarrow b\Vert cosθ}{\Vert \overrightarrow a\Vert} \overrightarrow a$, so, like the Eucledean result, $\Vert proj_{\overrightarrow a}\overrightarrow b\Vert=\Vert \overrightarrow b\Vert cosθ$ (2). From (1) and (2) we get $\overrightarrow a \cdot\overrightarrow b=\Vert \overrightarrow a\Vert\Vert proj_{\overrightarrow a}\overrightarrow b\Vert$, which is the geometric meaning of inner product.